# Getting file upload status without AJAX

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, upload, status

It seems to me if information is already being output to a user by a browser it ought to be accessible in the DOM in some manner via javascript.  When you upload a file using a webkit browser (and possibly others) using the good old iframe trick the browser displays an upload percent in the status bar at the bottom of the browser window.  It would be pretty amazing to be able to tap into that instead of needing to query the server for that same information.  Has anyone ever tried to do so?

Comment: It would be nice, but that API is not exposed to JavaScript. You'd need to use a plug-in.

Answer (score 0):

I have try something like this. If using old method with iframe for uploading files you can get upload information only if you have APC enable on server side (for php). With javascript the maximum that you can know is the start and the end of the upload (by using iframe onload event). So you can use an animated gif when file upload start and remove the animated gif when it ends (that causes the onload event of the iframe).

Then after upload iframe will contain any errors message of the upload status. You can do some more trick by returning file info as JSON when upload finish.